# Splitting a matrix based on certain values in the rows

Tags: loops, for-loop, matrix, octave

I have a matrix `A` like this:

```
A = [911 911; 
       0   2; 
       8   5; 
       7   3; 
     911 911; 
       5   3; 
       1   6; 
       6   7; 
     911 911; 
       3   5; 
       8   4];
```

I want to split the matrix `A` into three matrices (`A1`,`A2`,`A3`) based on the row values `911` like this:

```
A1 = [0 2; 8 5; 7 3]; 
A2 = [5 3; 1 6; 6 7];
A3 = [3 5; 8 4];
```

I need to do this thing inside a `for` loop which will give the spitted matrix one after another.

Here is my small code that will find out the row position to find out the `911` values:

```
key = 911;
headeridx = and(any(s1Table == key, 2), any(s1Table == key, 2));
row_position= find(headeridx);
```

Then I am puzzled about how to make a `for` loop (I need this loop) to generate the three matrices.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it.

```
    clear
    A = [911 911;
           0   2; 
           8   5; 
           7   3; 
         911 911; 
           5   3; 
           1   6; 
           6   7; 
         911 911; 
           3   5; 
           8   4];

     ar=0;
     n=1;
     for k=1:rows(A)
       if A(k,1)==911
         ar=ar+1;
         n=1;
       else
         q{ar,n}=A(k,1:2);
         n=n+1;
       endif
     endfor

     A1=cell2mat(q(1,:)')
     A2=cell2mat(q(2,:)')
     A3=cell2mat(q(3,:)')
```